# How to apply stochastic gradient descent to a regularized objective function?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I know that stochastic gradient descent is suitable for objective functions in the following form:

```
Q = sum(Qi)/N
```

where Qi is the contribution of the i-th observation.

However, I have found that in some academic works, the authors apply SGD and regularization at the same time. So how is SGD able to fit in this situation?

Comment: Gradient descent is a method for finding min of *any function* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent . Stochastic GD is one variant, it also is applicable to any function

Comment: @Maxim Thanks, but I don't know how to do that. SGD seems to split the objective function into components (observations) whose gradients are computed and applied successively, but regularizer terms are something independent of these components added to that objective function.

Comment: It seems that I have found the answer myself. The regularizer should be split and shared by the components, thus resulting in an additional coefficent of 1/N in the regularizer.